# Backup table content

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS and need to create a .bak of a table in one of the databases containing the content of that table.

The reason behind this is that I might need to populate the database again with this data at a later time (it is test data) and generating it again using the script I wrote takes to much time.

How do I do this in SSMS?

Comment: Why don't you just use Import/Export data to a dummy database?

Comment: Would be nice if I could share it with others by giving them a .bak saves them time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your response to WEI_DBA very literally and accepting you prefer a bak file, I suggest you create a second database, then copy the content of this specific table (eg. with 'select into') to the second database. You can then backup the second database in the regular way.

```
create database foo
select * 
  into foo.dbo.table1 
  from dbo.table1
backup database foo 
    to disk = 'c:\temp.foo.bak' 
  with format
     , medianame = 'foobak'
     , name = 'Full backup foo'
```

The thing is that your instinct tells you that you need a backup (.bak) file. This is not the best way to share the contents of the table. Users would have to restore it to a dummy database and then copy in the same way as you now have ahead.

Sharing the table content via csv or xml is in my opinion a better way (and for that you can indeed use the Import/Export wizard as mentioned earlier).